# Why componentDidMount does not get fired?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a function which fires when the user clicks on it. The function calls setState, and the component rerenders itself. The only problem is that componentDidMount() does not get fired. Here's the code:

```js
//the element which fires removeElem
    <div onClick={this.removeElem}>
        -
    </div>
    
//the removeElem function gets called
    removeElem = () => {
        this.setState({status: 'deleted'})
    }
//the component renders, the state has been changed
    render(){
        console.log(this.state.status) //the right value is logged after removeElem()
        return(
        //...
//componentDidMount
    componentDidMount(){console.log("mounted")} //not logging
```

Why?

Comment: Please make sure you include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example with your problem. The code sample you provided is insufficient to reproduce the issue you describe

Comment: `componentDidMount` should only be called once during any given lifecycle of a component. https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount - perhaps you want to try `componentDidUpdate` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `componentDidMount()` method just get trigerred when your component is mounted. You should use `componentDidUpdate()` method, that gets triggered when you update the state/props of your component.

You should read the React Docs for [State and Lifecycle](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html)

See the snippet below:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
    state = { status: 'active' }
    //componentDidMount
    componentDidMount(){console.log("mounted")}
   //componentDidUpdate
    componentDidUpdate(){console.log("new status:",this.state.status)}
    //the removeElem function gets called
    removeElem = () => {
        this.setState({status: 'deleted'})
    }
    //the component renders, the state has been changed
    render(){
        console.log(this.state.status) //the right value is logged
        return( <button onClick={this.removeElem}>
                Trigger it
        </button>);
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>,document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id='root'></div>
```